# New line button && submit button

Tags: react-native

In my `TextInput` I need to show a "New Line" key **and** also the "Done" key.

Currently I am only able to get one or the other. I can get the "New Line" key but setting `<TextInput returnKeyType="none" multiline>`, however I don't get the "Done" key anymore:

[image]

Is it posible to get both? I am testing on Android, I haven't tested on iOS yet.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the short answer is no.

For the [`returnKeyType`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype) the documentation states can only one of the enum values...

```
returnKeyType?: enum('done', 'go', 'next', 'search', 'send', 'none', 'previous', 'default', 'emergency-call', 'google', 'join', 'route', 'yahoo') 

Determines how the return key should look. On Android you can also use returnKeyLabel.
```

#### Cross platform

```
The following values work across platforms:

done
go
next
search
send
```

#### Android Only

```
The following values work on Android only:

none
previous
```

#### iOS Only

```
The following values work on iOS only:

default
emergency-call
google
join
route
yahoo
```

Comment: Darn, thanks Chris for the reply. Isn't it a common thing though to see in apps a new line key and a submit button where there is multiline input? I'm not a user of apps, and new to apps, so just curious. I vaguely remember this.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable thing, but it only really applies when the text input is the last item in your form, right? Not sure how common that is.

Comment: Ohh I now recall this, it's in the texting apps, they actually have the gui for the send button next to the input! And there is just a single key, that is the new line key. So they rely on using gui + keyboard. Very interesting, thanks for this chat Chris!